# TextField Corona (lua) sending characters

Tags: search, lua, coronasdk

I want to know how can I implement a "Search bar" where the user writes the text and this info will be send after the user click on button search or press Enter.

```
local campoBusqueda = native.newTextField( 50, 50, 300, 25 , onButtonRelease )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/02/07/tutorial-text-input-with-native-ui/

The info would be submitted on the submitted event.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you the code which i have used in my code but you can use this code as per your need -

local function fieldHandler( event )

if ( "began" == event.phase ) then

```
   -- This is the "keyboard has appeared" event
   -- In some cases you may want to adjust the interface when the keyboard appears.
```

elseif ( "ended" == event.phase ) then

```
    -- This event is called when the user stops editing a field: for example, when they touch a different field
```

elseif ( "submitted" == event.phase ) then

```
     -- This event occurs when the user presses the "return" key (if available) on the onscreen keyboard
     -- Hide keyboard
     native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )
 end
```

end

textField = native.newTextField( 75, 150, 165, 30,  fieldHandler )

textField.font = native.newFont( native.systemFontBold, 24 )

textField.inputType = "Name"

group:insert(textField)

I hope, it will help you..